# Want to get list of folders using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have a list of json files created inside a folder named using build id. Have to trace the folders in a directory to fetch last 5 builds json to project comparison. 
Finding difficulties in getting list of folders name in a directory using ajax call.

Comment: Mind sharing the code?

Answer (score 0):

Unless your HTTP server could provide you the list of those files, this will be hard. If you use Apache for example, adding this to your `.htaccess` will give you the list of files in your folder (if you do not precise a file in the URL):

```
Options +Indexes
```

You could find alternative if you use a different HTTP server.